# Does Paypal IPN mc_gross include shipping and handling?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to setup a Paypal payment on a website and I'm analyzing IPN response to the `cmd=_notify-validate` request. The [**official documentation**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) says that `mc_gross` is:

*Full amount of the customer's payment, before transaction fee is subtracted.*

From this statement, it seems that `mc_gross` includes all costs substained by customer (including shipping and handling costs). But documentation also talks about `mc_shipping` and `mc_handling`. So does `mc_gross` include shipping and handling or it's simply the sum of item costs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does - it is the full payment amount which means everything included. mc_shipping etc are just variables to track what shipping amount was passed to Paypal.